# jQuery UI error - f.getClientRects is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make jQuery UI work, but it doesn't. Here's what happens.

I'm loading dependencies:

```
<script src="assets/src/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="assets/src/js/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="assets/src/js/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="assets/src/js/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/src/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="assets/src/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="assets/src/js/main.js"></script>
```

That's my **main.js** file:

```
$(function () {
    $("input[type=submit]")
        .button()
        .click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
});


$(function () {
    $("#circum").buttonset();
});

$(function () {
    $("#dialog-message").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

When I run the code in Brackets jQuery UI is loaded but doesn't work, however, when I comment my *main.js* file out and then bring it back that's the error I get in the console and UI is suddenly working. It's extremely weird.

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: elem.getClientRects is not a function TypeError: elem.getClientRects is not a function
at jQuery.offset (http://127.0.0.1:27530/assets/src/js/jquery/dist/jquery.js:9779:14)
at Object.getWithinInfo (http://127.0.0.1:27530/assets/src/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:1157:26)
at jQuery.$.fn.position (http://127.0.0.1:27530/assets/src/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:1179:23)
at _position (http://127.0.0.1:27530/assets/src/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:8709:17)
at ._position (http://127.0.0.1:27530/assets/src/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:415:25)
at open (http://127.0.0.1:27530/assets/src/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:8334:8)
at .open (http://127.0.0.1:27530/assets/src/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:415:25)
at _init (http://127.0.0.1:27530/assets/src/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:8210:9)
at ._init (http://127.0.0.1:27530/assets/src/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:415:25)
at _createWidget (http://127.0.0.1:27530/assets/src/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:587:8) undefined
```

I've found this thread discussing the issue, but still wasn't able to fix it.

[Github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2804)

Cheers.

Comment: I'm thinking it could be a problem with Angular, since everything works fine on a new document without it, but I have no idea as to what the error even is.

Comment: can you please share the html? or please create a jsfiddle

Comment: Put jQuery and jQuery UI before angular in your list of `script`s.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I can't believe I'm that dumb! I appreciate it a lot! There are some other small issues arising but they're easily fixable. As far as I'm aware now, Angular conflicts with Jquery UI since they modify some of the same DOM elements.

Answer (score 85):

What version is your jQuery UI? I had the same issue with jQuery UI 1.11.4 and jQuery 3.0.
After installing jQuery UI 1.12.0-rc.2, the problem was fixed.

Comment: Worked for me thanks, but apparently it didn´t work for the m8

Comment: Didn't make a difference as to what version of Jquery UI it is, the fix in the comments above helped! Thank you anyway!

Comment: yes,of course,i use a compenent that not support jquery 3.0
i change the version of jquery and that rights

Comment: Ah, updated from 1.11.4 to 1.12.1 and that did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: This was the solution for me

Answer (score 49):

Adding the [jQuery 3 Migrate Plugin](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js) resolves this issue as noted [here](http://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/), updated UI will be coming out soon.

---

NOVEMBER 5, 2018 UPDATE

If using latest jQuery and jQuery UI , use [latest jQuery migrate](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/3.0.1/jquery-migrate.min.js) to prevent compatibility warnings/issues.

---

Comment: migrating sound awesome can affect on other code too.

Comment: I was using Jquery 3+ , changing to Jquery 1.9.1 with jquery-ui-1.9.2 solved the issue :)

Answer (score 31):

Turns out this is a compatibility between jQuery 3.x.x and jQueryUI prior to 1.12.0.

including below script resolved the issue for me.

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js

Answer (score 4):

I updated our legacy site, from jquery 1.12 to jquery 3.5 and hit this same problem.
The site is using jquery-ui 1.10 but sadly updating to jquery-ui 1.12 broke other things so I couldnt use that option.
Running the production site with the migration plugin felt wrong so instead I looked how this problem was fixed in jquery-ui 1.12.

Patching jquery-ui 1.10 with the fix from jquery-ui github ["Position: Guard against passing window to Offset"](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/b3a9b13a218cd90b7cf67be5d5f8ad6e76c557b0) worked for me.

This is an old post, but if someone like me need to update legacy sites, maybe this information can be useful.

Comment: What "other things" did jQuery-UI 1.12 break? I'm doing the same upgrade (jQuery 1.12 -> 3.5) and was just wondering why jquery-UI wasn't backward compatible.

Comment: Honestly I dont remember all of the issues, but one thing that stood out was the autocompletion in our dropboxes. It is listed in the [migration guide](https://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.12/#require-wrappers-for-each-autocomplete-menu-item) and even though it seemed simple to fix, it turned out to be a too big task with our legacy code.

Answer (score 2):

After doing all of the updates and STILL having the problem, I just fixed it in the code:

Look for this:

```
if ( !elem.getClientRects().length ) {
    return { top: 0, left: 0 };
}
```

Enter this just before it:

```
if (!elem.getClientRects()) {
    return { top: 0, left: 0 };
}
```

Comment: When I added this fix, I found another problem, where the drop down list wasn't showing up under the appropriate input box if the box or its container had a z-index over 10.

You can fix that by going to the jquery-ui.css, line 907 (.ui-widget-content ) and adding z-index: 4000; which will replace item under the box.  It's actually, but under the container on a lower index

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue with jquery-3.0.0. I have just included jquery-migrate.3.0.0 reference after jquery reference. Issue is resolved and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
> npm remove jqueryui
> npm i -S jquery-ui-dist
```

This will download a version of JQuery UI which can be included directly with `<script>` tags.

Comment: This is only for .NET.  This should be specified.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when I was trying to get X and Y position of the mouse using " .pageX/.pageY " on a click event.

Try to change the source of the libraries in order to get the latest update of them, making sure that they are compatible.

Those links are now working and they could fix the issues.