# detect mouse position over image

Tags: javascript, jquery

On an image (slideshow) I would like to detect on which side the courser is placed. e.g the left-half side of the image or the right-half side of the image. I would like to show an arrow (left and right) when the user is mouseover the image and depending on the location I will show the right or the left arrow. I just need to know how to achieve the detection of the mousemove over the image. Thanks!

Comment: why using `JavaScript` while you can achieve this using `CSS`.

Answer (score 0):

Use event `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` in `img` tag or `div` tag (you can divide two areas left-right in slideshow)

For example:

```
<img onmouseenter="showArrow(position)" onmouseleave="hideArrow(position)" src="">
```

- `onmouseenter` when the mouse pointer onto an image
- `onmouseleave` when the mouse pointer out of an image

Answer (score 0):

```
var imageElement = document.querySelector('.imageElement');
var arrowsElemennt = document.querySelector('.arrowsElement');

var setStatusForArrows = function(status){return function(){arrowsElement.style.display = status}};

imageElement.addEventListener('mouseover',setStatusForArrows('block'));
imageElement.addEventListener('mouseout', setStatusForArrows('none'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is some code that is able to detect the relative cursor position over an image. You could repurpose this to show/hide your arrow icons based on its return value (instead of the console.log).

Added `mouseout` listener for auto-hiding arrows.

```js
const img = document.getElementById('imageTest');
const [imgRects] = img.getClientRects();
// let showLeftArrow = false;
// let showRightArrow = false;
img.addEventListener('mouseover', evt => {
  const distanceLeft = Math.abs(evt.clientX - imgRects.left);
  const distanceRight = Math.abs(evt.clientX - imgRects.right);
  if (distanceLeft < distanceRight) {
    // showLeftArrow = true;
    // showRightArrow = false;
    console.log('left');
  } else {
    // showLeftArrow = false;
    // showRightArrow = true;
    console.log('right');
  }
});

/*
  img.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    showLeftArrow = false;
    showRightArrow = false;
  })
*/
```

```html
<img id="imageTest" src="https://vuejs.org/images/logo.png" style="height:30px;width:30px" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Isn't it possible to just use something more simple such as: $(".object-img").on("mousemove", function(event) {
        var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;        
    
     if (x < $(this).width() / 2 ) 
        
     console.log ("left");
   
   else 
    console.log ("right");
    
    });

Comment: I believe the offset values are going to be relative to their container, instead of the entire page: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft)

Comment: I am using jquery ... well, trying your script i get an getClientRects undefined. I am changing const to var as i am using vanilla js :-)

Comment: If you're able to I would update your question with a jQuery tag, if that's the solution you need. As for the `getClientRects` issue, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37914869/jquery-ui-error-f-getclientrects-is-not-a-function