# 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getClientRects' while use jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This is my JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#txtId").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller")',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: "{ 'mode': 'mode','prefix': '" + request.term + "' }",
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            var transformed = $.map(data, function (item) {
                                return item.Name;
                            });
                            response(transformed);
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert('error loading');
                        },
                    });
                },
            });
});
```

I get the error only when the "response(transformed);" is used. I have included all the required scripts, firstly jquery and next jquery-ui.js . I have included this in the bundle config. How should I resolve this error, I cam across lot of solutions stating that jquery.js or jquery-ui.js would not be loaded. But in my case both are loaded correctly. Can some one help me out on this?

Comment: Which browser are you getting this in? Internet Explorer?

Comment: Yes. Internet Explorer

Comment: Which version of jQuery UI do you use?

Comment: jQuery UI - v1.11.4

Comment: OK, that's the problem - it seems like it's an issue with versions before 1.12.00. It should go away if you upgrade the jQuery UI version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery UI error - f.getClientRects is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37914869/jquery-ui-error-f-getclientrects-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Tried with jQuery UI - v1.12.1. Still the same

Comment: No, It did not solve my case

Comment: Hmm, I see few people saying it's somehow related to jQuery (in addition to jQuery UI). Somebody fixed it by downgrading from jQuery 3 to 1.9.1 and using jQuery UI 1.9.2 with it solved it. Odd. Perhaps *some* of the newer versions have a problem but I can't find a definitive listing of which ones. Also, it might even be related to using specific versions of each jQuery and jQuery UI. I can't test it right now but perhaps just trying different versions for each until a combination works would be the way to do it.

Comment: Okay I will check on this

Comment: Please provide an example of the `data` that is returned and also the `transformed` results. Please use `console.log()` right away in your success callback and then again just before submitting the results.